# Test for LDA which takes a test json file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Below is the code of my LDA model. As a testing data I want to send a JSON file which is having contents in following format

> {"filename":"06930000002Uik0AAC_v003.txt","id":"06930000002Uik0","text":"
>   Getting started is wonderful here”}

Here filename is the name of the file , id is the file id and text will be the content of the file. I want the expected output for this to be an array of related Documents. Lets say Doc 1 and Doc 3. Are there any solution/link which I can refer. I am referring to the spark test suite defined [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/clustering/LDASuite.scala) but not getting the solution for this.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA 
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SQLContext} 
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType}

val lda = new LDA()   .setK(10)   .setMaxIter(10)   .setFeaturesCol("features")

val model = lda.fit(countVectors)

val transformed = model.transform(countVectors)
```

Comment: have you looked at this example ? https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/LDAExample.scala

Comment: I created a pipeline with tokenizer, remover, vectorizer -> did pipeline.fit(testdataframe) -> transformed the dataframe based on pipeline model -> Eventually my model looks like this

Comment: import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{CountVectorizer, CountVectorizerModel}
res89: (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)], Array[String], Long) = (MapPartitionsRDD[75256] at map at <console>:117,Array(reimbursement, number, getting, wonderful, slide, december, started, wonderfully, explained, fitness, fy13),1)

Comment: Pardon me if it is a dumb question, but I want to get the fileid which are related to my test data. How to get that? Correct me if I am wrong, In the example link they have not mentioned about the same